# displaying integer separated VBA in Access form

Tags: string, ms-access, vba, integer, concatenation

I am creating a form where I need to display an identifying number separated by "-" e.g I have an Identification number 1122313 and need to display it as 11-22-313 in a textbox in the form
The number is declared as long integer in the form's control source table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the form you have created, in the detail section (I assume), where you plan to display the number field with "-" between certain digits, locate the textbox control that you plan on using, then do the following:

1. View the properties for the textbox control (I assume you are using
   a textbox).
2. Locate the Format property (3rd down iv viewing all properties)
3. Enter the following value (without the quotes): "00-00-000"
4. Save the form changes, then view the results.

Comment: I updated the answer to give a step-by-step solution. I don't think tou meant "Me.text.box" did you? Probably "Me.textBox" or "Me.MyNbr"...

Comment: Yes thats what I meant, I tend to prefer code for my solutions but this is simple and saves me a lot of time and code, thanks!